# Why does my MOSFET only allow current when it is switched polarity (drain to GND)?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, voltage-regulator, switching

This circuit acts strangely.

I think the MOSFET is correctly placed. However, whenever I connect it to the power supply (1V 0.1A for initial testing) it doesn't let any current through - unless I switch its polarity, as in the drain connected to ground and source to positive side of the battery. I then get 1A of current and around 0.6V. I am not sure why this is. How can I fix it?

This is the code:

```
int FETPin = 6 ;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin( 9600 ); 
  pinMode(FETPin, OUTPUT);}
void loop () {
    analogWrite (FETPin , 255) ;
    delay(500);
    analogWrite (FETPin , 0) ;
    delay(500);}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the ground of the Arduino connected to the source of the MOSFET?  If not, there's no Vgs change happening.  When you turn the MOSFET around, you're seeing conduction through the body diode.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using analogWrite() to set the output of the Arduino pin? I assume you want an on/off switch so digitalWrite() would be preferable. Also can you measure the voltage at this pin when you have it "enabled" ?

Comment: Logical level MOSFET should be used, especially if MCU voltage 3.3V..

Comment: Is the FET broken due to 200uF of capacitance it needs to short to discharge it?

Comment: @vir Shouldn't the source be connected to the GND of the power supply rather that the arduino? Since the drain to source voltage/current will be high and will probably destroy my arduino.

Comment: The Arduino and power supply grounds should be connected together.  If the gate and source of the MOSFET are connected to independent circuits, the Arduino will apply 5V to the gate relative to its own ground and you will not be able to control it.  Like @user263983 said, a logic level MOSFET is a better choice instead of the 20V one, but you should be seeing at least a bit of current with Vgs of 5V.

Answer (score 0):

What my be missing here is that source of the transistor needs to be connected to the ground of the arduino **AND** the ground of the arduino needs to be connected to the ground of the power supply. Remember that ground is just a reference potential, if you don't have the same reference for your gate control voltage then the circuit won't work.

To further clarify, you need a certain VGS for the FET to turn on. The gate voltage is provided by the arduino. However, what's the reference potential (i.e. ground) of the arduino? If it's not the same as the one from the power supply then you won't have the proper VGS needed to turn on the device.

Comment: Thank you! it worked :)